# Flutter web http request badCertificateCallback

Tags: http, flutter, flutter-web, dio

I was wondering if any you can point me to a web flutter library that had http badCertificateCallback. I tried [DIO](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio) but it is giving me an error and submit an issue but I haven't heard from them yet

DIO code:

```
Dio dio = new Dio(options);
(dio.httpClientAdapter as DefaultHttpClientAdapter).onHttpClientCreate =
(client) {
client.badCertificateCallback =
(X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
};

Error: Expected a value of type 'DefaultHttpClientAdapter', but got one of type 'BrowserHttpClientAdapter'
```

I also tried [http](https://github.com/dart-lang/http), but it doesn't have a bad Certificate Callback, we could use this but it isn't web-compatible

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.badCertificateCallback =
        ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);
    IOClient ioClient = new IOClient(httpClient);
response = await ioClient.post(url, body: data, headers: headers);
```

Any comment will be more that apreciate.

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: That would be a terrible security hole. If you want to temporarily accept a self-signed certificate, add it to the browser's trusted certs.

Comment: Hi,@DanielHernandez I have the same problem with you, have you found the solution for your question?

Comment: Hi, have the sema issue. Is there any solutions already?

Answer (score 4):

With 5.2.0 release of [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio/changelog), according to the documentation we can do the following.

```
dio.httpClientAdapter = IOHttpClientAdapter(
          createHttpClient: () {
            // Don't trust any certificate just because their root cert is trusted.
            final HttpClient client =
                HttpClient(context: SecurityContext(withTrustedRoots: false));
            // You can test the intermediate / root cert here. We just ignore it.
            client.badCertificateCallback =
                ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);
            return client;
          },
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I use `badCertificateCallback` with DIO this way:

```
//import 'package:get/get.dart' hide Response hide FormData; //<-- if you use get package
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

void main(){
  HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides{
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context){
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback = ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) {
        final isValidHost = ["192.168.1.67"].contains(host); // <-- allow only hosts in array
        return isValidHost;
      });
  }
}

// more example: https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/tree/master/example
void getHttp() async {
  Dio dio = new Dio();
  Response response;
  response = await dio.get("https://192.168.1.67");
  print(response.data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a http Client like this,

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:dio/adapter.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'dart:io' as IO;
....
....
....
/// CLIENT
static Future<Dio> _dioClient() async {

Dio dio = Dio(await _getOptions()); // Getting Headers and Other data

if(!kIsWeb){
  (dio.httpClientAdapter as DefaultHttpClientAdapter).onHttpClientCreate =
      (IO.HttpClient client) {
    client.badCertificateCallback =
        (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
    return client;
  };
}
return dio;                                                             
}
```

Comment: This one actually works.  but onHttpClientCreate is now deprecated. do you have the updated code for .createHttpClient ?

Comment: @chitgoks See Asim's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

you can just turn this part of your to this one

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  client.badCertificateCallback =((X509Certificate cert, String  host, int port) => true);
```

Comment: this won't work on Fultter-Web `Unsupported operation: Platform._version`

Comment: I did it this way, (dio.httpClientAdapter as IOHttpClientAdapter).createHttpClient = (HttpClient dioClient) {
      dioClient.badCertificateCallback = ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);
      return dioClient;
    } as CreateHttpClient?; but dio.get() doesnt work. im not sure what the right syntax for this is. onHttpClientCreate worked for me