# CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED while using dio 3.0.10

Tags: flutter

When I try to post a request I get

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: ok(handshake.cc:354))
```

my code (provided in the example)

```
 Future login() async {
final request = {
  "j_username": "user1",
  "j_password": "pass1",
};

 final response = await _dio.post('/itim/restlogin/login.jsp', data: request);
//get cooking from response
final cookies = response.headers.map['set-cookie'];
if (cookies.isNotEmpty && cookies.length == 2) {
  final authToken = cookies[1].split(';')[0]; //it depends on how your server sending cookie
  //save this authToken in local storage, and pass in further api calls.

  aToken = authToken;
  print("authToken");
//saving this to global variable to refresh current api calls to add cookie.
  print(authToken);
}

print(cookies);
//print(response.headers.toString());
```

}

Comment: it works with HttpClient but i cant seem to resolve it with dio, does dio has any option to resolve it ?

Comment: [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60890158/4317297). Or just use a valid certificate...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means your website doesn't have a valid certificate.

Please add the below code to fix this.

```
 (_dio.httpClientAdapter as DefaultHttpClientAdapter).onHttpClientCreate =
         (HttpClient dioClient) {
       dioClient.badCertificateCallback =
           ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);
       return dioClient;
     };
```

Like this

```
Future login() async {
final request = {
  "j_username": "user1",
  "j_password": "pass1",
};
(_dio.httpClientAdapter as DefaultHttpClientAdapter).onHttpClientCreate =
             (HttpClient dioClient) {
           dioClient.badCertificateCallback =
               ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);
           return dioClient;
         };

 final response = await _dio.post('/itim/restlogin/login.jsp', data: request);
//get cooking from response
final cookies = response.headers.map['set-cookie'];
if (cookies.isNotEmpty && cookies.length == 2) {
  final authToken = cookies[1].split(';')[0]; //it depends on how your server sending cookie
  //save this authToken in local storage, and pass in further api calls.

  aToken = authToken;
  print("authToken");
//saving this to global variable to refresh current api calls to add cookie.
  print(authToken);
}

print(cookies);
```

**Make sure you comment code when you have a valid certificate.**

Comment: Dio has deprecated classes `DefaultHttpClientAdapter` and `onHttpClientCreate` `Dio plan to remove this classes from release of 6.0.0`. So the updated answer is here,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77005574/2079023 and dio documentation link is here https://pub.dev/packages/dio#https-certificate-verification Hope this will help you. Thanks.